# How do I find feed from IP Camera

Tags: network-programming

Recently I purchased an IP camera. It's a SafeHome 278041-NORDIC (if anyone is curios).

How do I access the feed? I want to make a program, where I have to use it. I'm guessing that it's a link.

If I go to the camera's IP-address in a browser, then it asks me to login, and then I just enter the camera's main menu. But I can see, that it has some kind of structure in there, because if I go to 'Settings', then it takes me to the URL: 10.0.0.34/web/admin.html . So I imagined that the actual feed from the camera would be something along the lines of: 10.0.0.34/stream.mjpeg

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.ispyconnect.com/ to detect what feed address is served from your ip camera or you can use http://ipcamlive.com.